What kind of commutative rings lift to the sphere?
Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring. By a "lift to the sphere" I mean a commutative ring spectrum $\mathbb{S}_A$ such that $A \simeq \mathbb{S}_A\otimes_{\mathbb{S}} \mathbb{Z}$ as commutative ring spectra, where $\mathbb{S}$ is the sphere spectrum. For which $A$ does this exist, and can it be made functorial?
If $A$ is a polynomial algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$, then the spherical polynomial rings are such lifts. More generally if $A = \mathbb{Z}[G]$ for abelian group $G$, then it lifts to $\mathbb{S}[G]$.  Another example in the $p$-complete setting is when $A = W(k)$ is the $p$-typical Witt vectors (e.g. $k$ is a char. $p$ finite field, in which case we have the spherical Witt vectors).

Pardon the very naive question but what happens if you pick any presentation of $A$ as a quotient of a polynomial ring and consider the corresponding quotient of polynomial rings over $\mathbb{S}$? I assume the idea is that this produces higher homotopy in general? If so, what about a more refined version where we resolve $A$ by a free simplicial ring (I mean here a simplicial object whose terms are polynomial rings) and consider the realization of the corresponding commutative ring spectrum?

@QiaochuYuan You cannot do this a priori: it is unclear how you could lift a simplicial diagram of polynomial rings to a simplicial diagram of ring spectra (I guess that you could lift edges, but not higher coherent homotopies).

There are known obstructions. If I understand correctly, for every prime $p$, there is a $\delta$-structure on $A$, coming from the Tate diagonal of $\mathbb S_A$ and the Segal conjecture. You should consult Thomas Nikolaus and Achim Krause — they thought about this (cf. Achim's talk at IHÉS in the K-theory workshop last summer).

@Qiaochu Yuan Cofibers of commutative ring spectra do not need to even have a unital multiplication, so I think the hard part is to coherently lift the multiplication

@atticusw: again I am very ignorant about these things but I don't have in mind taking a cofiber here (since that doesn't do the right thing for ordinary commutative rings either). The way you quotient a ring $R$ by an ideal $I$ while staying entirely inside the category of rings is to use $I$ to define a congruence on $R$, namely ${ (r, s) : r \equiv s \bmod I }$; this is another ring equipped with a pair of morphisms to $R$ and you take their coequalizer. So the analogous construction in homotopy land is a geometric realization.

@QiaochuYuan I see what you mean (I'm also a beginner in this subject so don't trust me too much). My first suspicion is that maps of polynomial rings cannot always be lifted to $E_\infty$ maps between their spherical counterparts. (They can always be lifted to $E_1$ maps but I don't think it is necessarily $E_\infty$, since the free $E_\infty$-algebra in one generator is not $\mathbb{S}[x]$ but something quite complicated.)

The construction for Witt vectors of finite fields was effectively given in
"Schwänzl, R.; Vogt, R. M.; Waldhausen, F.
Adjoining roots of unity to $\mathbb{E}_\infty$ ring spectra in good cases—a remark. Homotopy invariant algebraic structures (Baltimore, MD, 1998), 245–249,
Contemp. Math., 239, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1999",
and these authors also proved that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ cannot be lifted to the sphere.

@atticusw I guess that it is even not clear how to do it for $E_1$-maps: although the free $E_1$-ring on $x$ is $\mathbb S[x]$, it seems unclear how you produce maps out of the two-variable $E_1$-ring $\mathbb S[x,y]$.

You can lift polynomial rings ($\mathbb{S}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ can be written as suspension spectrum of the monoid $\mathbb{N}^n$), but not all maps between them. For example already $\mathbb{S}[x] $ does not admit an $E_\infty$ endomorphism taking $x\mapsto x+1$.
